# Replace column value of Pandas with another if any single attribute match (identify if two columns have common attribute)

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming a sample dataframe:

```
   Chemical   Compound     Name
0   Alcohol    Ethanol   Liquor
1     Hooch        NaN   Liquor
2   Cerveza    Ethanol      NaN
3   Bauxite  Aluminium Gibbsite
4  Feldspar  Aluminium      NaN
```

What is the efficient way to replace or identify if two rows are ***identical***? (Assuming two rows are *identical* if **any** attribute(column) match and not necessarily all of them)

The resulting could be either:

```
   Chemical   Compound     Name
0   Alcohol    Ethanol   Liquor
1   Alcohol        NaN   Liquor
2   Alcohol    Ethanol      NaN
3   Bauxite  Aluminium Gibbsite
4   Bauxite  Aluminium      NaN
```

or:

```
   Chemical   Compound     Name Identifier
0   Alcohol    Ethanol   Liquor    Alcohol
1     Hooch        NaN   Liquor    Alcohol
2   Cerveza    Ethanol      NaN    Alcohol
3   Bauxite  Aluminium Gibbsite    Bauxite
4  Feldspar  Aluminium      NaN    Bauxite
```

Comment: `df.duplicated()`?  What do you mean the rows are identical 'if any attribute(column) match'?  Example?

Comment: @Alexander For example in the above dataframe: Alcohol, Hooch and Cerveza are "identical" (Alcohol and Hooch have Liquor common and Bauxite and Feldspar have Aluminium common)

Comment: Do you have either networkx or scipy available?  While we can do this in pure Python/pandas, it's easier to use existing functions.

Comment: I think networkx  is good way for this type of question

Comment: DSM Wen I am not familiar with networkx. I will give it a read. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a set consolidation / connected components / union-find question in disguise.

If we arbitrarily decide to view it as a connected components problem, we can imagine every word in your frame as a node.  A a row basically says that the elements there are equivalent, or in other words, reachable: there are edges between the nodes.  To determine the set of synonyms, we need to find the connected components of the graph.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df.stack().reset_index(), source='level_0', target=0)
codes = {v: i for i, vv in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)) for v in vv}
df["Identifier"] = df["Chemical"].groupby(df["Chemical"].replace(codes)).transform("first")
```

gives me

```
In [229]: df
Out[229]: 
   Chemical   Compound    Name Identifier
0   Alcohol    Ethanol  Liquor    Alcohol
1     Hooch        NaN  Liquor    Alcohol
2   Cerveza    Ethanol     NaN    Alcohol
3   Bauxite  Aluminium     NaN    Bauxite
4  Feldspar  Aluminium     NaN    Bauxite
```

because once we make the graph with edges (equivalencies)

```
In [233]: G.edges()
Out[233]: 
[(0, 'Alcohol'),
 (0, 'Ethanol'),
 (0, 'Liquor'),
 ('Ethanol', 2),
 ('Liquor', 1),
 (1, 'Hooch'),
 (2, 'Cerveza'),
 (3, 'Bauxite'),
 (3, 'Aluminium'),
 ('Aluminium', 4),
 (4, 'Feldspar')]
```

we can ask networkx to find the groups:

```
In [234]: list(nx.connected_components(G))
Out[234]: 
[{0, 1, 2, 'Alcohol', 'Cerveza', 'Ethanol', 'Hooch', 'Liquor'},
 {3, 4, 'Aluminium', 'Bauxite', 'Feldspar'}]
```

And then the rest is just turning these into numbers and arbitrarily choosing to use the first Chemical entry as the name of each group.

We could do exactly the same thing by using scipy's scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components function, with a little bit more setup, or simply use an off-the-shelf set consolidation algorithm to find the groups.  For example, using the set consolidation algorithm [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation#Python:_Iterative), we could do

```
In [240]: consolidate([set(row.dropna()) for _, row in df.iterrows()])
Out[240]: 
[{'Alcohol', 'Cerveza', 'Ethanol', 'Hooch', 'Liquor'},
 {'Aluminium', 'Bauxite', 'Feldspar'}]
```

and once again we have the groups we need.

Answer (score 1):

To identify rows that have at least one matching column:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().duplicated()).any(axis=1)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

In the above, rows 1, 2 and 4 are 'duplicates'. Row 1: Liquor, Row 2: Ethanol, and Row 4: Aluminum.

I'm not clear about your fill logic, however.